# Matching Strings to be case insensitive

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

In my application I have status of an event.
I have created an object for those status while writing test scripts like this:

```
var satus = {
open : 'Open',
inProgress : 'In-Progress'
closed : 'Closed'
};
```

I have that status displayed in many pages of the application and at different pages it is written in Upper Case letters while not in others.

Can we expect Strings as insensitive?

Comment: are u referring asking about Javascript? if so, it is case sensitive

Comment: do you want the strings do be all in lowercase or uppercase? or just the original way the strings are?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, string comparison is case sensitive.

You can compare two strings case insensitively with the following code.

```
var equal = str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use ReGex with the `i` flag to make it case insensitive.

Depending on your use-case, it may be convenient to use a RegEx matcher with the `i` flag to make it case-***in***sensitive, like so:

```js
'Test'.match(/test/)  //=> null
'Test'.match(/test/i) //=> ["Test", index: 0, input: "Test", groups: undefined]
```

This works especially well when wanting to do partial matches:

```js
'Test'.match(/te/)  //=> null
'Test'.match(/te/i) //=> ["Te", index: 0, input: "Test", groups: undefined]
```

Comment: If match is needed in jest, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970044/check-if-a-string-contains-abc-or-cde-with-jest/57970118#57970118

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
for(var key in status) {
    var value = status[key].toLowerCase();
    console.log(value);
}
```