# Check if a string contains 'abc' or 'cde' with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I would like to check if a string contains 'abc' or 'cde' with jest.

```
const substr1 = 'abc'
const substr2 = 'cde'
const str = 'ooocdeooo'
```

I am using

```
expect(str).toContain(substr1);
```

for one string but I cant find a clean way to check whether substr1 or substr2 is in str
How could I do that ?
Thanks !

Comment: You can try regex test `expect(/(abc|cde)/i.test(str)).toBe(true)`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use a regexp with [`toMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchregexp--string)

like :

```
expect(str).toMatch(/(abc|cde)/i)
```

Comment: You can/should add `/i` at the end for case insensitivity

Comment: The link seems to now be https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchregexp--string

Answer (score 60):

You can use `toContain` Jest matcher
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem

> ### .toContain(item)
>
> Use `.toContain` when you want to check that an item is in an array. For testing the items in the array, this uses `===`, a strict equality check. `.toContain` can also check whether a string is a substring of another string.
>
> For example, if getAllFlavors() returns an array of flavors and you want to be sure that lime is in there, you can write:
>
> ```
> test('the flavor list contains lime', () => {
>  expect(getAllFlavors()).toContain('lime');
> });
> ```

Comment: This is the method used by the author of the question.

Comment: Regarding OP question: I believe using 2x `expect(...).toContain(...)` - for each string is the way to go. Or is there any reason to make test code more complicated by using regexp just to have 1 `expect` instead of 2?

Answer (score 21):

You might also be looking for one of like these

```
expect.stringMatching(/(abc|def)/i)
expect.stringContaining("abc")
```

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to match a variable, and inserting a variable into a Regex (like in the accepted answer) looked complicated. Instead, I found success with:

```
const tree = renderer.create(<Component {...mockProps} />).toJSON();
const treeString = JSON.stringify(tree);

expect(treeString.includes(mockProps.individualProp)).toBeTruthy();
```

[More info here on .includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Answer (score 0):

Jest makes it so easy to [write your own matchers](https://redd.one/blog/practical-guide-to-custom-jest-matchers) it would be a sin not to.

Here's my take at `toContainAny`:

```js
expect.extend({
  toContainAny(actual, strings) {
    const found = strings.filter(s => actual.includes(s))
    const pass = found.length > 0
    const asStr = strings.join(", ")
    const which = pass ? 'none' : 'one'
    const message = () => `Expected ${which} of [${asStr}] to be in "${actual}".`
    return {pass, message}
  },
})
```

A matcher just needs to return an object of the following shape:

```js
{
  pass: boolean
  message(): string
}
```

The extra fluff is just to produce a correct message in case someone reverses  the meaning of your matcher with `.not`:

```js
describe("toContainAny matcher", () => {
  test("normal", () => {
    expect("a b c").toContainAny(["a", "d"])
  })

  test("reversed", () => {
    expect("a b c").not.toContainAny(["f", "g"])
  })
})
```

It's more readable and more versatile than the regex solution.