# how extract value from calc function in tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I am trying to create a test in which I want to compare the width of an element after it has been resized by dragging it. The problem is that the resize library returns the width value as

```
calc(50% - 4px)
```

The only thing that changes is this percentage value and this is what I want to compare in the test if it is bigger or smaller depending on the mouse movement to the right or left.

However, I do not know how to extract only the percentage value or possibly the subtraction result from this string.

```
  it("has resizable containers", async () => {
    const initialRightWith = rightContainer.style.width;
    expect(initialRightWith).toEqual("50%");
  });
```

Expected: "50%"
Received: "calc(50% - 4px)"

Comment: Use [`toContain`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57970044/215552) instead of `toEqual`?

Comment: yes, but then I need the extracted percentage to check if it is bigger or smaller than the next one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to get the percentage from your string, here's an example:

```js
const width = 'calc(50% - 4px)';
const regex = /^calc\((\d{1,3})%.+$/;

const getPercentageFromCalc = (w) => {
  const matches = regex.exec(width);
  
  return matches[1];
};

console.log(getPercentageFromCalc(width));
```

Remember to add checks to make sure your regular expression matched something, this is just an example!